# Saving a blob file to disk with buffer using Cordova PhoneGap File and Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, html5-filesystem

I'm using Cordova PhoneGap and HTML5 to build an android app that saves video's from a GoPro to the androids flash memory.

My issue is that the short videos are 3-5mb in size and when writing to flash in the current code lock the app for 3-4 seconds during the `fileWriter.write()` call.

Android version 4.4.0,
PhoneGap 3.6

Is it possible to use a buffer or the create writer in another thread to stop the app freezing for the file write duration?

If anyone has some insight on a better approach to achieving this would be much appreciated.

```
var src = new Blob(); //3-5mb blob from previously retrieved file
var starttime = Date.now();
fileSystem.root.getFile("NEWFILE.MP4", { 'create': true }, 
    function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function (event) {
                console.log(Date.now()-starttime); //usually 3-6 seconds lockup
        };
        fileWriter.write(src);
    }, function (fail) { console.log(fail); });
});
```

Comment: File operations in phonegap is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks Murtaza, any idea why the write operation would lock up UI? I've recorded timestamps around fileWriter.write() and that is the only time consuming operation.

Comment: Probably there are other items running in background..